# Vue Router next callback always called in beforeEach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am creating a guard for some urls. I am using `beforeEach` to evaluate a meta parameter and decide if a user can see a page or not.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  var isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('cacheTokenId');

  if(to.meta.guestOnly && isLoggedIn) {
    next({ name: 'cars' })
  } else if(to.meta.authOnly && !isLoggedIn) {
    console.log("authOnly")
    next({ name: 'login' })
  }

  next()
})
```

My problem is that the last `next` (the one outside conditions) always gets executed. I thought `next()` stopped the execution at the point where it was called.

For now, my solution has been moving last `next()` inside an `else` condition:

```
if(to.meta.guestOnly && isLoggedIn) {
    console.log("guestOnly")
    next({ name: 'cars' })
  } else if(to.meta.authOnly && !isLoggedIn) {
    console.log("authOnly")
    next({ name: 'login' })
  } else {
    next()
  }
```

Why is this needed, am I missing something?

Comment: write return statement after next, it wont reach to next()

Comment: @Atul, thanks for the suggestion. I thought about that. but all examples I have found does not have it, so I was wondering if something else missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought `next()` stopped the execution at the point where it was called.

`next()` is just a function call, it won't do something outside of the language spec. It doesn't throw an exception, so it won't stop the flow.

> all examples I have found does not have [[a return statement after `next()`]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881872/vuejs-router-beforeeach#comment90715378_51881872)

This is because every example you've found avoids calling `next()` more than once in a navigation guard handler with the usual logic we would find in JavaScript, like an explicit `else` like you're using.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually they use next() as I use it. Your answer makes sense, thanks!